# How to exit a Qthred completely? I find that when I exit a thread, vscode shows that the thread is still running

Tags: multithreading, qt, pyqt, qthread

When I debug my pyqt application in vscode, I find that when I exit some threads, vscode shows that those threads are still running.

I created three thread classes in my application by inheriting QThread. And for some reason, I want to instantiate these three classes in the main thread through class method. That's why I use signals and slots in both running and stopping threads.

Here is my complete code:

```py
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QPushButton, QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget
from PyQt6.QtCore import QTimer, QThread, pyqtSignal
import sys
import uuid


class Task(QThread):
    startSignal = pyqtSignal()
    stopSignal = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        super(Task, self).__init__()
        self.uuid = uuid.uuid4()
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.timeoutEvent)
        self.startSignal.connect(self.startEvnet)
        self.stopSignal.connect(self.stopEvent)

    def timeoutEvent(self):
        print(f"This task's uuid is {self.uuid}")

    def startEvnet(self):
        self.timer.start(2000)
        self.start()

    def stopEvent(self):
        self.timer.stop()
        self.quit()
        self.wait()


class SSHClient(QThread):
    startSignal = pyqtSignal()
    stopSignal = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        super(SSHClient, self).__init__()
        self.tasks: list[Task] = []
        self.startSignal.connect(self.startEvent)
        self.stopSignal.connect(self.stopEvent)

    def run(self):
        # .... other long time work
        for task in self.tasks:
            task.startSignal.emit()

    def startEvent(self):
        self.start()

    def stopEvent(self):
        for task in self.tasks:
            task.stopSignal.emit()
        self.quit()
        self.wait()

    @classmethod
    def fromOtherClass(cls, other=None):
        client = cls()
        client.tasks.append(Task())
        return client


class SSH(QThread):
    startSignal = pyqtSignal()
    stopSignal = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        super(SSH, self).__init__()
        self.ssh_clients: list[SSHClient] = []
        self.startSignal.connect(self.startEvent)
        self.stopSignal.connect(self.stopEvent)

    def run(self) -> None:
        # ... other work
        for client in self.ssh_clients:
            client.startSignal.emit()

    def startEvent(self):
        self.start()

    def stopEvent(self):
        for client in self.ssh_clients:
            client.stopSignal.emit()
        self.quit()
        self.wait()


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.resize(300, 300)
        self.btn = QPushButton("run", self)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.btnEvent)

    def btnEvent(self):
        if self.btn.text() == "run":
            self.btn.setText("stop")
            self.ssh = SSH()
            self.ssh.ssh_clients = [SSHClient.fromOtherClass()]
            self.ssh.startSignal.emit()
        else:
            self.btn.setText("run")
            self.ssh.stopSignal.emit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

When I ran the above code as debug in vscode, I found that when I clicked the `run` button, the application created two threads. When I pressed the button again (`stop`), vscode showed that the previously created thread was still running.

Every time I restart running afterwards, two new threads always appear, and the previous threads will not exit.
The following is a screenshot of the vscode runtime stack:
[image]

As described above, what can I do to stop those thread, which should be stoped?

Comment: It's not possible to stop a thread. You can only ever stop the code that is running inside the thread. If the code is running a blocking loop, the thread must wait until it finishes - it cannot force it to terminate. It's up to you to provide a mechanism for breaking out of the loop. The thread can only stop after the `run` function returns.

Comment: @ekhumoro Thanks. What I am quite puzzled about is whether it will have an impact on computer resources if a long-term task in a thread is stoped but the thread itself is still running?

Comment: As I said: the thread stops when `run` returns. It cannot do anything until you restart it.